# Using phalcon's DI from singleton?

Tags: php, phalcon

Let's imagine, that we're developing extremely simple singleton Auth class dealing with DB and session (we don't want any other decomposition like auth adapters etc).

How can I make DI available from this singleton class?
Of course, best way is to pass DI instance to constructor, but what if I want it from singleton? Should I use static setter method `Auth::setDi($di)` or better practices are available? Or maybe we should avoid singletons because we always have DI storage?

I'm sorry for my english, I hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the latest DI instantiated statically:

```
<?php

$di = Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
```

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#accessing-the-di-in-a-static-way